# Hilbert Transform of an FM Signal

Tags: hilbert-transform, frequency-modulation

The Hilbert Transform of an Amplitude Modulated signal returns the envelope of the signal. What does the Hilbert transform of a Frequency Modulated signal return? How can I use the Hilbert Transform to get the sidebands of a Frequency Modulated signal?

Comment: Just a nitpick: a signal's envelope is the the _amplitude_ (or absolute value) of its Hilbert transform.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am aware that the amplitude of the HT is the signal's envelope. What would be the equivalent for the FM signal though? Is it also the envelope of the signal?

Comment: Yes, it's always the envelope -- the HT "doesn't care" how the signal was modulated. Keep in mind that you can also use the phase, though.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/3094/1024) great answer . .

> If we have a real-valued sequence x(n)x(n), and the Hilbert transform
>   of x(n)x(n) is xH(n)xH(n), the analytic signal, a(n)a(n), associated
>   with x(n)x(n) is:
>
> a(n)=x(n)+jxH(n)
>
> Computing the magnitude of a(n)a(n) will give you the instantaneous
>   envelope of the original x(n)x(n) sequence. This works great for AM
>   demodulation. If you compute the instantaneous phase of a(n)a(n) to
>   get ϕ(n)ϕ(n), and compute the time derivative of ϕ(n)ϕ(n), you have FM
>   demodulation.

A practical example where we generate an FM signal in Matlab and analyse it looks as follows:

```
fs = 44.1e3; %// sample rate
dt = 1/fs;
fc = 200; %// carrier
df = 50; %// modulation excursion (Hz)
fm = 4; %// modulation rate (Hz)

tAx = dt:dt:1; %// time axis in seconds
u = sin(2*pi*fc*tAx + (df/fm)*cos(2*pi*fm*tAx));
w = unwrap(angle(hilbert(u)));
v = diff(w)/(2*pi*dt); %// instantaneous phase differential normalized to Hz
```

Plotting u and v then gives the following plot, where the sidebands occur at the extremes of the signal . .

[image]